# How do you reference a Rails engine route from another engine outside of a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

My Rails application is sending an email (outside of a view/controller) that references a route from another internal engine (let's call it `VenueApplication`).

I really don't want to hard-code the url, is there a way of referencing the routes from another engine?

I've found references for doing this within the rails app:

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.edit_person_url(@person, 
  host: 'server.com'
)`

But how can I do this for a route in the `VenueApplication` engine?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

`VenueApplication::Engine.routes.url_helpers.edit_person_url(@person,
  host: 'https://engine.com'
)`

Comment: VenueApplication IS the engine name.

Manage::Engine.routes.url_helpers